# Ошибка с умножением матриц. Numpy

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, матрицы

Я хочу ускорить свою программу на `python3` с помощью библиотеки `numpy`, но выходные данные у двух решений различаются, я не могу понять в чем проблема. Вот два фрагмента кода, первый фрагмент выдает правильные выходные данные, но он медленный, а второй фрагмент быстрый, но выдает неправильные выходные данные. Я хочу сделать так, чтобы код был быстрым как втрой фрагмент и при этом выдавал правильные выходные данные как первый.
Первый фрагмент:

```py
import numpy as np

def matrix_multiply(inp_tri, matrix):
    out_tri = inp_tri @ matrix[:3, :3] + matrix[3, :3]
    w = inp_tri @ matrix[:3, 3] + matrix[3, 3]
    w[w == 0] = 1.0
    out_tri = out_tri / w[:, None]

    return out_tri


perspective_matrix = np.array([
        [(1.0 / tan(45 / 180 * pi)), 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
        [0.0, (WIDTH / HEIGHT) * (1.0 / tan(45 / 180 * pi)), 0.0, 0.0],
        [0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0],
        [0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0]
    ])


def get_projection(translated_vec):
    projection_vec = matrix_multiply(translated_vec, perspective_matrix)

    projection_vec += 1.0
    projection_vec = projection_vec * H_SIZE

    return projection_vec


obj = np.array([[
        [0, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 1],
        [-2, -2, 2]
    ]])

for i, translated_vec in enumerate(obj):
    translated_vec = get_projection(translated_vec)

    drawing_obj.append(translated_vec)

print(drawing_obj)
```

Второй фрагмент:

```py
import numpy as np


def matrix_multiply(inp_tri, matrix):
    out_tri = inp_tri @ matrix[:3, :3] + matrix[3, :3]
    w = inp_tri @ matrix[:3, 3] + matrix[3, 3]
    w[w == 0] = 1.0
    out_tri = out_tri / w[:, None]

    return out_tri


perspective_matrix = np.array([
        [(1.0 / tan(45 / 180 * pi)), 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
        [0.0, (WIDTH / HEIGHT) * (1.0 / tan(45 / 180 * pi)), 0.0, 0.0],
        [0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0],
        [0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0]
    ])


def get_projection(translated_vec):
    projection_vec = matrix_multiply(translated_vec, perspective_matrix)

    projection_vec += 1.0
    projection_vec = projection_vec * H_SIZE

    return projection_vec


obj = np.array([[
        [0, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 1],
        [-2, -2, 2]
    ]])

projection_vecs = get_projection(obj)

print(projection_vecs)
```

Выходные данные первого фрагмента:

```py
 [[[360.         432.           1.8       ]
  [343.05238413 560.22497458   1.72190976]
  [576.86750905 282.77045599   1.78547349]]]
```

Выходные данные второго фрагмента:

```py
 [[[360.         460.11248729   1.85810604]
  [347.81142717 560.22497458   1.55690117]
  [562.18247889 259.88751271   1.78547349]]]
```

**Правка 1.**
Я убрал ту часть кода которая идентична в обоих фрагментах кода и которая не влияет на выходные данные.

**Правка 2.**
Я добавил пример массива `obj`, при котором выходные данные будут отличаться.

**Правка 3.**
Я добавил выходные данные каждого фрагмента и сделал полноценный код, чтобы каждый смог его запустить.

Comment: Вместо вызова `translated_vecs = rotate_triangle_y(angle, obj) + obj_pos` приведите пример эталонных векторов. Не более десятка, но необходимо, чтобы на них вычисления проекций давали разный результат.

Comment: @PakUula я добавил эти вектора

Comment: А как из вновь добавленного вывода понять, что оба фрагмента работают по-разному?  Ну проведите в конце концов нормальный дебагинг! Покажите хоть какие-то промежуточные результаты. Из обоих фрагментов, что-бы понятно было, в какой точке они начинают расходиться?  Тогда можно будет хоть что-то сказать. А пока - непонятно что, непонятно где, и непонятно почему вас не устраивает.

Comment: @passant какой массив им не подай, в каждой точке они будут расходится, в примере который я привел, всего один полигон, из трех точек. И в выводе что я показал, проиллюстрировано какие выходные данные выдают функции для этого полигона

Comment: Еще раз.  Читаем внимательно, что вы написали. "первый фрагмент выдает правильные выходные данные... а второй фрагмент....выдает неправильные выходные данные." Потом вы вывели результат ОДНОГО (скорее всего) второго\фрагмента, а по логике , должны показать результат работы ДВУХ фрагментов. Тогда хоть о чем-то можно будет говорить. А так, первое, что приходит в голову, в get_projection() вы в качестве параметра передаете в  "фрагментах" разные по размерности объекты.  Далее он передается в matrix_multiply, в которой задействована операция @, которая очень чувствительна к размерности параметров.

Comment: вы все правильно плняли, вот я и хотел понять что нужно изменить, чтобы подавая обьект другой размерности, выходные данные не искажались, а выходные данные которые я показал, это выполнение работы двух фрагментов кода просто совмещенных в один, и визуализация выходных данных от каждого фрагмента

Comment: "а выходные данные...это выполнение работы двух фрагментов кода просто совмещенных в один" -  И в итоге ничего никому не понятно. Еще раз. Приводим два фрагмента, для каждого приводим результаты его работы, которые отличаются. Вы же понимаете, что в том виде, что вы привели,  ваш код у себя на компьютере никто запустить не может. Поэтому  необходимо вставить в коды промежуточный, отладочный вывод, и показать его результаты. Именно так и выполняется отладка программ. А идеально было бы привести два ПОЛНОСТЬЮ АВТОМНОМНЫХ фрагмента, что-бы их можно было запускать у себя и искать в них ошибку.

Comment: Сейчас это два автономных фрагмента @passant

Answer (score 2):

У меня такое впечатление, что я вас уговариваю. В вашем "автономном фрагменте" -  как минимум библиотека math не подключена, не заданы константы, не определена переменная drawing_obj. Исправить эти ошибки не трудно, но это означает, что вы даже не пытались эти фрагменты самостоятельно автономно запустить. И вы предлагаете в такой каше кому-то ковыряться и искать, где у вас ошибка. Нормально.

Как я уже сказал выше -  у вас ошибка в модуле `matrix_multiply`. Я вам подсказывал, что с оператором `@` надо работать очень аккуратно. У вас в одном случае вы в эту функцию передаете в качестве первого параметра двумерный массив, а во втором случае - одномерный(!) массив, первый элемент которого представляет собой двумерный массив. Соответственно и результат получаете разный.

Исправьте в вашем втором варианте `projection_vecs = get_projection(obj[0])` и результаты будут тождественны.

Как эти все манипуляции способны ускорить вашу программу - мне остается совершенно непонятно.  Но на вопрос -  *как исправить ошибку умножения*, вынесенный вами в заголовок  -  я ответил.