# Оптимизированное умножение матриц. Numpy

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, матрицы

У меня есть массив `obj`, в котором хранятся матрицы, каждый из которых мне надо умножить на матрицу `projection_vec`. Когда программа перебирает все элементы `obj`, и умножает каждый из них на `projection_vec`, и тогда результаты умножения такие какие мне нужны, но когда программа умножает сразу весь массив `obj` на `projection_vec`, результаты немного отличаются, я не знаю как это исправить, так как умножение сразу всего массива `obj` в разы быстрее чем перебирать и умножать каждый элемент массива по отдельности, скажите пожалуйста что мне нужно изменить во втором фрагменте кода, чтобы результаты были как в первом фрагменте, но при этом код выполнялся с такой же скоростью (или даже быстрее) как второй фрагмент.

**Фрагмент 1**

```py
import numpy as np
from math import *


def matrix_multiply(inp_tri, matrix):
    out_tri = inp_tri @ matrix[:3, :3] + matrix[3, :3]
    w = inp_tri @ matrix[:3, 3] + matrix[3, 3]
    w[w == 0] = 1.0
    out_tri = out_tri / w[:, None]

    return out_tri


perspective_matrix = np.array([
        [(1.0 / tan(45 / 180 * pi)), 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
        [0.0, (WIDTH / HEIGHT) * (1.0 / tan(45 / 180 * pi)), 0.0, 0.0],
        [0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0],
        [0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0]
    ])


def get_projection(translated_vec):
    projection_vec = matrix_multiply(translated_vec, perspective_matrix)

    projection_vec += 1.0
    projection_vec = projection_vec * H_SIZE

    return projection_vec


obj = np.array([[
        [0, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 1],
        [-2, -2, 2]
    ],
    [
        [1, 1, 1],
        [0, 1, 2],
        [-2, -2, -2]
    ]])

drawig_obj = []

for i, translated_vec in enumerate(obj):
    translated_vec = get_projection(translated_vec)

    drawing_obj.append(translated_vec)

print(drawing_obj)
```

**Выходные данные:**

```
[(array([[            nan,             nan,            -inf],
       [ 1.28000000e+03,  1.00000000e+03,  1.00000000e+00],
       [-1.42108547e-13, -2.80000000e+02,  1.50000000e+00]]), (255, 255, 255)), (array([[1.28e+03, 1.00e+03, 1.00e+00],
       [6.40e+02, 6.80e+02, 1.50e+00],
       [1.28e+03, 1.00e+03, 2.50e+00]]), (255, 255, 255))]
```

**Фрагмент 2**

```py
import numpy as np
from math import *


def matrix_multiply(inp_tri, matrix):
    out_tri = inp_tri @ matrix[:3, :3] + matrix[3, :3]
    w = inp_tri @ matrix[:3, 3] + matrix[3, 3]
    w[w == 0] = 1.0
    out_tri = out_tri / w[:, None]

    return out_tri


perspective_matrix = np.array([
        [(1.0 / tan(45 / 180 * pi)), 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
        [0.0, (WIDTH / HEIGHT) * (1.0 / tan(45 / 180 * pi)), 0.0, 0.0],
        [0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0],
        [0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0]
    ])


def get_projection(translated_vec):
    projection_vec = matrix_multiply(translated_vec, perspective_matrix)

    projection_vec += 1.0
    projection_vec = projection_vec * H_SIZE

    return projection_vec


obj = np.array([[
        [0, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 1],
        [-2, -2, 2]
    ],
    [
        [1, 1, 1],
        [0, 1, 2],
        [-2, -2, -2]
    ]])

projection_vecs = get_projection(obj)

print(projection_vecs)
```

**Выходные данные:**

```
[(array([[ 6.40e+02,  3.60e+02,  5.00e-01],
       [ 1.28e+03,  1.00e+03,  1.00e+00],
       [-6.40e+02, -9.20e+02,  1.50e+00]]), (255, 255, 255)), (array([[ 1.28e+03,  6.80e+02,  1.00e+00],
       [ 6.40e+02,  6.80e+02,  5.00e-01],
       [-6.40e+02, -2.80e+02,  2.50e+00]]), (255, 255, 255))]
```

Comment: чем этот вопрос принципиально отличается от https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1376481/%d0%9e%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d1%81-%d1%83%d0%bc%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%86-numpy ?

Comment: @strawdog тем что он сформулирован правильней, чтобы не было вопросов и ответов как здесь https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1376481/Ошибка-с-умножением-матриц-numpy

Comment: Ну так и переформулируйте свой первый вопрос. иначе такие вопросы будут закрываться как дубликаты.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В том ответе я вам советовал провести отладку. Понаставлять дополнительных выводов и посмотреть, что-же происходит в вашей программе. Даже показал, в какой функции стоит в первую очередь искать ответ. Вместо этого вы опять прибежали на форум, что-бы вашу работу за вас кто-то сделал.

Подсказываю, проблема у вас в операторе

```
out_tri = out_tri / w[:, None]
```

В одном случае `w` - это одномерный массив и первая координата пробегает по его значениям, во втором случае - это двумерный массив, и что вы при этом на что делите -  можно только догадаться. Я не знаю, какой вариант правильный, и что на что согласно алгоритму надо делить, но вот так формально, просто изменив вызов перейти от одного алгоритма к другому - не удастся.

Comment: Ок, спасибо, теперь до меня наконец-то дошло, что вы мне столько времени пытались сказать, спасибо!