# Оператор умножения матриц @ и Numpy

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, оптимизация, матрицы

Я хочу ускорить функцию умножения матриц вот с таким кодом:

```py
def matrix_multiply(inp_tri, matrix):
    out_tri = inp_tri @ matrix[:3, :3] + matrix[3, :3]
    w = inp_tri @ matrix[:3, 3] + matrix[3, 3]
    out_tri = out_tri / w[:, np.newaxis]

    return out_tri
```

Я нашел код на `github` в котором умножение матриц тех же размерностей сокращено до простого оператора `@`:

```
def scale(self, scale_to):
    self.vertexes = self.vertexes @ scale(scale_to)
```

Я попытался сделать так же, но получил вот такую ошибку:

```
ValueError: matmul: Input operand 1 has a mismatch in its core dimension 0, with gufunc signature (n?,k),(k,m?)->(n?,m?) (size 4 is different from 3)
```

Вот как выглядит функция после изменений (так же как у парня на `github` но с моими названиями переменных):

```py
def matrix_multiply(inp_tri, matrix):
    out_tri = inp_tri @ matrix

    return out_tri
```

Я не могу понять, почему у парня на `github` такая фишка работает, а у меня нет.

Вот пример моих входных данных:

```
inp_tri = np.array([[
        [0, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 1],
        [-2, -2, 2]
    ],
    [
        [1, 1, 1],
        [0, 1, 2],
        [-2, -2, -2]
    ]])

matrix = np.array([
                  [(1.0 / tan(45 / 180 * pi)), 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
                  [0.0, (WIDTH / HEIGHT) * (1.0 / tan(45 / 180 * pi)), 0.0, 0.0],
                  [0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0],
                  [0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0]
              ])
```

[Вот код из github](https://github.com/StanislavPetrovV/Software_3D_engine)

То что я жду от функции:

```py
out_tri = [[[        nan,  0.       ,  -0.5       ],
            [        inf,  1.77777778,  0.        ],
            [       -inf, -3.55555556,  0.5       ]],

           [[ 1.       ,   0.88888889, -0.        ],
            [ 0.       ,   0.88888889, -0.5       ],
            [-2.       ,  -1.77777778,  1.5       ]]]
```

Comment: я думаю проблема с размерностями. надо чтобы количество рядов одной матрицы соответствовало количеству столбцов другой и наоборот

Comment: @splash58 само собой, и у меня с размерностями ситуация даже лучше, чем у парня с гитхаба

Comment: Что, опять?  В одном из комментариев к вашему вопросу https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1376481/Ошибка-с-умножением-матриц-numpy я вам сказал " операция @, которая очень чувствительна к размерности параметров". Вы советы  запоминаете? Тут у вас та-же ошибка. А еще я вам посоветовал научиться проводить отладку программы самостоятельно, и даже подсказал как ее делать?  Вы к советам прислушиваетесь?

Answer (score 2):

Вы пытаетесь умножить матрицу `inp_tri` размерности `(2, 3, 3)` на матрицу `matrix` размерности `(4, 4)`. Матричное произведение так не работает. Матрицы  `A` и `B` можно перемножить только в том случае если последняя размерность матрицы `A` равна первой размерности матрицы `B`. Для двух двумерных матриц это означает, что число столбцов первой матрицы должно равняться числу строк второй матрицы.

В вашем случае последняя размерность трехмерной матрицы `inp_tri` - `3` а первая размерность двумерной матрицы `matrix` - 4. Следовательно такие матрицы перемножить невозможно.

```
In [270]: inp_tri.shape
Out[270]: (2, 3, 3)

In [271]: matrix.shape
Out[271]: (4, 4)
```

Comment: но ведь как-то у парня с гитхаба это получилось :-/

Comment: @zolars, очевидно у парня с гитхаба размерности совпадали ) Вы конечно можете попробовать оспорить правила умножения матриц, но для этого вам придется придумать свою альтернативную арифметику матриц :-D